# Is there a way to modify AWS existing resource using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, roles

I'm trying to modify a trust relationship in an existing AWS IAM role.
Is  there a way to do that using cloudformation?

Comment: AWS CloudFormation is primarily used to _deploy_ infrastructure. It is not aware of things created outside of CloudFormation. Individual actions such as changing the Trust Relationship in an IAM Role is not what CloudFormation was designed to do, unless it created the IAM Role initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to @Marcin 's response, once you've imported your resource to CFN, use the following documentation on performing [CFN Stack Updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks.html), specifically it is considered best practice (1) to update using [CFN Change Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html) method

(1) - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#cfn-best-practices-changesets

Answer (score 0):

You have to first [import it to CFN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) and then you will be able to modify it. Alternatively, you can develop a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) which will allow you to do whatever you want (its custom after all).